# How to insert int values into matrix by using if statement with char conditioning?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I'm having trouble with this situation where I need to put values inside a matrix based on user char input, here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int mat[2][2] = { NULL };
    char sex;

    printf("Insert gender (m or f):");
    scanf_s("%c", &sex);
    if (&sex == "m") {
        mat[0][0] = 1;
        }
    if (&sex == "f") {
        mat[0][0] = 2;
    }
    else{
        mat[0][0] = 3;
        printf("invalid\n");
    }
    printf("inserted: %c \n", sex);

    printf("value on matrix 00: %i\t", mat[0][0]);
    //printf("%i\n", mat[0][1]);
    //printf("%i\t", mat[1][0]);
    //printf("%i", mat[1][1]);

    return 0;
}
```

The values at the end seem to be right but the program don't runs as I expected and I can't see my mistake, any help?

Comment: `if (&sex == "m") {` Should be `if (sex == 'm') {` - you are comparing characters not strings (and even if you wanted to compare strings, what you have is not how to do it ;-)

Comment: @John3136: Right. `if (&sex == "m")` actually compares *addresses*, not strings. It tests whether the array corresponding to the string literal `"m"` has the same address as the `char` object `sex`. It doesn't.

Comment: `int mat[2][2] = { NULL };` should be `int mat[2][2] = {{0}};` You initialize each element to a `int` value (by initializing the first value to `0` and the remaining values are initialized to zero by default), not the pointer value `NULL`. This will allow you to print all elements. Also **note:** if your next attempted read is with `"%c"` (or `"%[...]"`) you will read the `'\n'` you have left in your input buffer (`stdin`). For reading a single-char from `stdin`, `getchar()` is proper. (note the return type).

Comment: You are, for some strange reason, comparing the addresses of characters with string constants.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Presumably because the compiler complained about `sex == "m"`.

Comment: @NicHartley Hence the rule that if you make any changes you don't understand, you must revert them before asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, operator == cannot be used to compare strings. To do so, you should use the function *strcmp* from *string.h*. In any case, what you need is not to compare strings, but to compare characters (and what you are doing is to compare an address with a string). My suggestion: scan a char instead of a string (using *scanf* instead of *scanf_s*) and change your equality tests from *&var == "val"* to *var == 'val'*. Also some tips in the code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //name your variables properly
    //initialize them immediately to avoid undefined values
    //respect its types: use '\0' instead of 0 for chars, and 0 instead of NULL for ints

    char gender = '\0';
    int matrix[2][2] = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
    
    //display accurate messages to the user
    
    printf("Select a gender (m or f): ");
    
    //don't scan a string if you only need a char
    //always check the return of a scan
    
    if(scanf("%c", &gender) <= 0)
    {
         printf("Input error\n");
         return 0;
    }
    
    //switch is usually more efficient than else-ifs
    
    switch(gender)
    {
        case 'm':
            matrix[0][0] = 1;
            break;
        
        case 'f':
            matrix[0][0] = 2;
            break;
        
        default:
            printf("Invalid gender\n");
            return 0;
    }
    
    printf("Selected gender: %c\n", gender);
    printf("Value on matrix[0][0]: %d\n", matrix[0][0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int mat[2][2] = {{0}};` will suffice. You should always check the return of `scanf` to protect against the (1) user canceling input with a manual `EOF`, (2) a *matching-failure* (not relevant to `"%c"`) or (3) an *input-failure*. A `switch` does work nicely there. (some with quibble that a `break;` is proper even in the `default` case -- even though case-fallthough isn't possible as the last expression)

Answer (score 0):

`&sex == "m"` compares the address of `sex` with the address of the string literal `"m"`, which will presumably evaluate to false.  This is not what you want.

You should compare the value of `sex` with the *character* literal `'m'`, as in:

```
if (&sex == "m") {
    // ...
}
```

The same goes for `&sex == "f"`, which should be `sex == 'f'`.